# Openldap slapd command not found

Tags: php, active-directory, openldap

currently I am trying to create active directory login by using PHP and OpenLDAP. But, when I tried to start the OpenLDAP, an error appear:

> -bash: slapd: command not found

What's wrong with that? How can I fix it?

FYI: I have tried to googling it, and I don't found something related to this error.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Active Directory, you don't have any need to start 'slapd' at all, that being the OpenLDAP *server.*

The only way your question makes sense is if you're using the OpenLDAP *client.*

Answer (score -1):

first check whether you have openldap installed.

```
rpm -qa | grep ldap
```

If it is there, you can start it by

```
/usr/local/libexec/slapd
```

You need to switch to root before you run it.